Prevent VSCode Debugger from closing the debugging session at the end of the script OR Enable breakpoints in the interactive window
There are two functionalities between the debugger and interactive window that I would like to have together rather than jumping between the two modes, these are:

Keep the debugging session/workspace variables open and accessible after the script is done
Use breakpoints and line-by-line debugging

VSCode automatically closes the debugging session and wipes the variables from the workspace after finishing the last line in a script, while the interactive window lacks breakpoints and line-by-line debugging.
How do I either prevent the debugger from closing the session at the end of the script, or enable breakpoints and line-by-line debugging within the interactive window?
I would prefer the second option (breakpoints in interactive window) because the debugger variable viewer is horrendously bad. (Addressed here with a solution that worked until May 2024 when VSCode deprecated it presented here)

For your first situation, you could prevent the debugger from ending the process by adding breakpoints. For the second one, the interactive window does not currently support marking breakpoints, you could raise a feature request for this function in the github.
